# mongoquery search string starts with a particular letter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using nodeJs want to write a mongoquery where want to give a letter in match filter for a particular key. Which will return all the objects in which the key value starts with that letter

example:

```
{emp_code:"H1234"},
{emp_code:"H1235"},
{emp_code:"P1234"},
{emp_code:"P1235"}
```

how to filter only `emp_code` that starts with "`H`"

Answer (score 1):

Use `collection.find({ 'emp_code': /^H/ })`. Using [nodejs mongodb driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) :

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/testDB", function(error, db) {

    db.collection("collection").find({ 'emp_code': /^H/ }).toArray(function(error, res) {
        console.log(res);
    });

});
```